# Use old style search box in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9

Is there any way to recover the old style search box we had in IE8 and below?

I cannot use the new "smart search" in the address bar.  I need to search programming stuff which contains special characters and dots and it is constantly mis-interpreted or straight up blocked by the new IE search in the address bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in way to restore the dedicated search box, its functionality (or most of it, at least) is now included in the address bar.

If IE is misinterpreting your search query, perhaps it's because it thinks you've entered an URL. To force the address bar into search mode, either type a question mark before your query, or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

Alternatively, you can install a toolbar that includes a dedicated search box, like the [Bing Bar](http://toolbar.discoverbing.com/toolbar/en-us.html) or [Google Toolbar](http://www.google.com/toolbar/ie/index.html).